# PayPal ExpressCheckout - You do not have permission to make this API call

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I have integrated a simple online form that demands some input from the user and has the item and pricing information in hidden fields.
After the user verified his inputs he hits the button to pay with PayPal and will be redirected to PP where he can pay instantly.

The PP URL is

```
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
```

for the sandbox and

```
https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
```

for the live environment paypemnt.

In the sandbox everything works fine when I use the sandbox credentials. After I set the URLs to live, changing the API credentials to the live credentials I am receiving the error

```
You do not have permission to make this API call.
```

I have tested and verified the following:

- the PP account is a business account and verified
- the form has been checked and approved as PP app by PayPal
- the form uses the correct API credentials
- set "Accept payments from your shop before configuring an API" to "YES" and saved it with the submit/save button
- checked the http request parameter live and they are looking fine

The error occours after sending the parameters from setExpressCheckoutData().

Now I am confused. I've red some infos to set MODE "test" to "live" at the end of the cart but don't know exactly what that means.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Found the reason and fixed it.

Removed the parameter "subject" from the request data. If this parameter isn't passed (I think it is necessary for Unipay only) the ExpressCheckout works fine.

In the sandbox it doesn't matter wether to use this parameter or not.